# The maximum pentahedron in a sphere

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, spheres

Suppose that there exists a pentahedron in a sphere whose radius is $1$ and that each vertex of the pentahedron can exist on the surface of the sphere.

> **Question** : What is the max of the volume of such pentahedron (if it exists)?

We can separate [pentahedra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentahedron) into the following three types :

[image]

Type $A$ : The faces are one quadrilateral and four triangles.

Type $B$ : The faces are three quadrilaterals and two triangles which are parallel.

Type $C$ : The faces are three quadrilaterals and two triangles which are not parallel.

The followings are what I've got. Let $V(A)$, for example, be the function of the volume of type $A$.

- $V(A)\le \frac{64}{81}$. The equality is attained for a square pyramid (both the length of the side of the square and the height are $\frac 43$).
- $V(B)\le 1$. The equality is attained for a regular triangular prism (the length of the side of the equilateral triangles is $\sqrt 2$ and the length between the triangles is $\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}$).

However, I don't have any good idea about how to treat type $C$. Can anyone help?

**P.S. 1** : I've just got another result. If a quadrilateral $ABCD$ is a rectangle and a side $EF$ is parallel to a side of the rectangle (say type $Z$), then $V(Z)\le 1$ and the equality is attained for the regular triangular prism above. Note that type $Z$ includes some of type $A$ (when $E=F$ as @Lucian comments), all of type $B$, some of type $C$.

[image]

Comment: You can imagine the pyramid as a degenerate case of the prism, obtained when one of the segments uniting the two points belonging to the triangles in question has length zero.

Comment: @Lucian: Nice observation. I added another result, but I'm stuck.